# check or change keyboard typing language from server or client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, keyboard

how can we check or change keyboard typing language from server or client side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect the language you can use this Goggle API:
http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v1/using_rest_langdetect.html

You will have to send the request from the Server side code as there's no JSONP exposed, they didn't provide ASP.NET sample but translating from PHP to C# should not be difficult.

Comment: No problem, however I'm one guy only. Feel free to thank the others on their own answers if you like. :)

Comment: really thanks @Shadow Wizard  : whould you plz give us some explain about your link / i know php very little , so need some help about this api!

Comment: @LostLord sure, see this: http://atsung.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/google-ajax-language-in-aspnet/ the code there should be exactly what you need and you might not even need the .NET proxy like I thought.

Comment: dear @Shadow Wizard thanks a lot for answer me again - but this new link just was a translator -> what was your point?

Comment: @LostLord no, it's not "just a translator" - it's using JavaScript code to call Google API `google.language.detect(text, function(result)` in which it pass `text` to the API and among other things, the result contains the language of the text - `result.language` will hold what you need. All the other things done later in that code are not relevant to you..

Answer (score 3):

You can't control this from the browser (or server).

Would you really want any random website to be able to change your typing language without your intervention?

Comment: but i saw this job in a national web site some years ago ... there was an imagebutton next to a textbox that could change en language / besides when we wanted to type on that textbox , told us plz change your typing language by the next button!!!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but...

You could fake it by intercepting the keypress of your user in client-side javascript and then adding characters to the textbox in javascript.

Comment: i think this is the last way that we can use dear @Eyal / however thanks for suggestion...